# Combine remote filter and local filter

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter

Now, I have a store which needs `remoteFilter: true` and

```
Ext.getStore("AccessRuleStore").addFilter([
    new Ext.util.Filter({
        id:'from',
        property: 'from',
        value   : Ext.getCmp("ruleFrom").getValue()
    }),
    new Ext.util.Filter({
        id:'to',
        property: 'to',
        value   : Ext.getCmp("ruleTo").getValue()
    })
]);
```

This `addFilter` automatically fires a call to the server, where `from` and `to` are used to calculate which rules to send to the client, because only the server knows which `from` and `to` values match which rule (for some reason, the list of `from` and `to` values cannot be disclosed to the client).

On the other hand, Rules can be active or inactive, and the indicating bool is always transmitted to the client. Now I want to add a checkbox "only show active rules", which filters the rules for `(rule.get("active")===true)` on the client side.

Is this possible, and how? Whenever I add filters to the store, the store thinks it is a remote filter, and asks the server what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `store.filterBy` which performs local filter only.

E.g.

```
rulesStore.filterBy(function (rule) {
    return rule.get('active');
});
```